# Odd situation .htaccess file with Win Server2k using Helicon Tech ISAPI Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect, helicontech

I am having issues with an older .htaccess file not accepting URL's that are case insensitive.

I need all URL's to be case insensitive, but I have to keep rewriting everything manually which seems completely horrible in practice.

Currently, I have to do this for each URL I want to be un-cased:

```
RewriteRule ^Page/(.*) /page/$1 [NC]
```

Prior to this, the only URL that would resolve was:

```
http://www.domain.com/Page
```

Now, any case exception works (post domain):

```
http://www.domain.com/Page
                     /page
                     /pAgE
                     ...etc
```

This isn't an issue on servers I use without the Helicon Tech ISAPI Rewrite module, but I didn't see anything in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install ISAPI_Rewrite. This isn't right. NC-flag has always been working.

Comment: Thanks, but no changes Andrew.

Comment: Try to contact Helicon's helpdesk they are good and will try to take a look at this.